# How to use Spring Profiles in configuring a Spring Job

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-profiles

I need to run a Spring batch job. My requirement is to run a few steps in sequence/parallel depending on the spring profile

I placed the Job config to run steps in parallel in a spring config file **parallel.xml**

```
<job id="job" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
incrementer="incrementer">

<step id="step1" next="step2">
    <tasklet ref="tasklet" />
</step>

<split id="step2" task-executor="assetStepAsyncTaskExecutor">
    <flow>
        <step id="split1">
            <tasklet ref="tasklet" />
        </step>
    </flow>
    <flow>
        <step id="split2">
            <tasklet ref="tasklet" />
        </step>
    </flow>
</split>
<listeners>
    <listener ref="listener" />
</listeners>
</job>
```

and the Job config to run steps in sequence in a spring config file default.xml

```
<job id="job" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
incrementer="incrementer">

<step id="step1" next="step2">
    <tasklet ref="tasklet" />
</step>
<step id="step2" next="step3">
            <tasklet ref="tasklet" />
</step>
<step id="step3">
    <tasklet ref="tasklet" />
</step>
<listeners>
    <listener ref="listener" />
</listeners>
</job>
```

And I am toggling between the job configs using Spring profile.

```
<beans profile="parallel">
<import resource="classpath:/spring/parallel.xml" />
</beans>

<beans profile="default">
<import resource="classpath:/spring/default.xml" />
</beans>
```

I am loading the config files through the contextConfigLocation context-param in web.xml.

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>
// other config files
classpath*:/spring/default.xml
classpath*:/spring/parallel.xml
</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I am passing the profile details as context-params

```
<context-param>
<param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
<param-value>default</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
<param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
<param-value>parallel</param-value>
</context-param>
```

If I don't include the files in contextConfigLocation it doesn't load the spring beans in default.xml and parallel.xml and because of this I get a NoBeanFoundException

```
Error creating bean with name 'controller' defined in class path resource [config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'batchJob' while setting bean property 'job'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'batchJob' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895) [spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425) [spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3780) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:163) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'batchJob' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:527) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1083) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:274) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 26 more
```

If I include both the config files. I get a DuplicateJobException.

```
12/21/2017 17:00:58,971 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) JBWEB000287: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.DuplicateJobException: A job configuration with this name [batchJob] was already registered
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.AutomaticJobRegistrar.start(AutomaticJobRegistrar.java:164) [spring-batch-core-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.AutomaticJobRegistrar.onApplicationEvent(AutomaticJobRegistrar.java:128) [spring-batch-core-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97) [spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:303) [spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:911) [spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:428) [spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3780) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:163) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.DuplicateJobException: A job configuration with this name [batchJob] was already registered
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry.register(MapJobRegistry.java:52) [spring-batch-core-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.DefaultJobLoader.doLoad(DefaultJobLoader.java:152) [spring-batch-core-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.DefaultJobLoader.load(DefaultJobLoader.java:114) [spring-batch-core-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.AutomaticJobRegistrar.start(AutomaticJobRegistrar.java:161) [spring-batch-core-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:]
    ... 19 more
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Just to make clear, you want one job to be defined depending on spring active profile, either parallel or sequential?

Comment: Yes. Few steps in the job will run in parallel or in sequence depending on the active profile.

Comment: May I ask which version of Spring you use, and if you can create a github repo to demonstrate the situation?

Comment: Spring batch core - 2.1.8
Spring core 3.0.5 
Spring batch integration - 1.2.1
I will try to create a project with this set up.
- Thanks!

Comment: Please take a look [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8203). It seems that `default` profile was added in Spring 3.1. Maybe this is the issue you're stuck on? If so, either try upgrading Spring version (a little) or try defining a different profile for `default` job configuration (kind of my deleted answer).

Comment: You are right. I tried using version 3.1 and it worked. Here's a repo with what I've tried. https://github.com/karthikch53/spring-profile

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch each job name has to be unique which is defined as id="job" while configuring the job. Above configuration trying to setup two jobs with same job name as "batchJob" which is why you are seeing the exception.

To achieve what you need you do this.

```
 <job id="jobA" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
incrementer="incrementer">

<step id="step1" next="step2">
    <tasklet ref="tasklet" />
</step>

<split id="step2" task-executor="assetStepAsyncTaskExecutor">
    <flow>
        <step id="split1">
            <tasklet ref="tasklet" />
        </step>
    </flow>
    <flow>
        <step id="split2">
            <tasklet ref="tasklet" />
        </step>
    </flow>
</split>
<listeners>
    <listener ref="listener" />
</listeners>
</job>


<job id="jobB" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
incrementer="incrementer">

<step id="step1" next="step2">
    <tasklet ref="tasklet" />
</step>
<step id="step2" next="step3">
            <tasklet ref="tasklet" />
</step>
<step id="step3">
    <tasklet ref="tasklet" />
</step>
<listeners>
    <listener ref="listener" />
</listeners>
</job>
```

From you controller you can call either jobA or jobB based on the context parameter.

Comment: I don't think having same job names was the issue. https://github.com/karthikch53/spring-profile/tree/master/src/main/resources/spring/batch/jobs This config worked for me.

Comment: can you share the complete project?

Answer (score 0):

As @lzagkaretos Suggested in the comments, the issue was with the Spring version. Updating the version to 3.2.2.RELEASE resolved the issue for me.